# How do I define a class that passes method calls through a different class's methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ie

```rb
class B
  def method_1
  end
  def method_2
  end
  #Additional methods
end

class A
  def initialize instance_of_b
    @b = instance_of_b
  end
  def method_1
    #custom behavior
  end
  #For all other methods, call b.method
end
```

I know you can accomplish this by having B be a parent of A, but in my particular case that wouldn't make sense; is there a way to do this without using inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged question with Rails, ActiveSupport has [`Module#delegate_missing_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate_missing_to) method

```
class B
  def method1
    'foo'
  end

  def method2
    'bar'
  end
end

class A
  delegate_missing_to :@b

  def initialize(b)
    @b = b
  end

  # custom behavior
  def method1
    super.upcase
  end
end
```

```
b = B.new
a = A.new(b)

a.method1 #=> "FOO"
a.method2 #=> "bar
```

Answer (score 4):

This is what [`SimpleDelegator`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) is for:

```
class B
  def method_1
    'foo'
  end
  def method_2
    'bar'
  end
end

require 'delegate'

class A < SimpleDelegator
  def method_1
    super.upcase
  end
end
```

It automatically creates a constructor that takes the object you want to delegate to:

```
b = B.new
a = A.new(b)

a.method_1 #=> "FOO"
a.method_2 #=> "bar"
```

Comment: No need `require 'delegate'` if it's rails as OP tagged

Answer (score 0):

One alternative perhaps worth mentioning:

```
require 'forwardable'

class A

  extend Forwardable

  def_instance_delegators :@b, :method1, :method2, :method3

end
```

With this, a `a = A.new; a.method2` would aktually do a `@b.method2` in the A-instance `a`.

While this requires you to type the list of the methods you want to forward, this has the advantage that A really gets new methods of this name, which of course does not happen with an automatism based on, say, `method_missing`.